# I can't get react up and running. When i type npm start then it gives me an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npx, npn

As you can see i get this error. Has it something to do with my package.json? Default looks like this.

```
{
    "name": "reactproject",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.12.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
        "react-scripts": "3.3.0"
    }
}
```

```
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\k12\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-31T00_09_26_886Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\k12\reactproject> ^C
```

After i did the command npm rm -g create-react-app i get the following in the command prompt

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\k12'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorMessage (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-message.js:38:39)
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:201:13)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:171:20)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97
  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97:27)
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:150:25)
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 7

C:\Users\k12>
```

Comment: try using `node server.js` if u have a server.js file.

Comment: No it did not help but thanks anyway. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have no `start` script defined in your `package.json`

As I don't know what your server set up is, I cannot say what is should be exactly. But something along the lines of:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
}
```

Comment: Can you try to read my post again i tried to remove an older version and now i cannot create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `package.json`, your project seems to be a Create React App project without a template. This occurs when you have an older, globally installed CRA on your machine. The default template package.json should look like this:

```
{
  "name": "test3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Remove the globally installed version (`npm rm -g create-react-app`) and try again with `npx create-react-app reactproject`

See the https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started guide for more information.

Comment: Yes i did that. I created my project with the following.

Comment: Be sure that you don't have a globally installed CRA on your computer (`npm rm -g create-react-app`)  and try again. It should notify you about an older version existing if there is one (A template was not provided)

Comment: when i try to start the new folder the command prompt says i use a older version of create-react-app and therefor no template could be created.

Comment: See the comment and updated answer: you must remove the older version first with `npm rm -g create-react-app`. After that try running the command again. If the issue persists then you probably have yet another copy of the create-react-app on your machine.

Comment: I did what you said. The problem presist. What to do from here?